# Using sed to get a specific part of a text

Tags: html, sed

I am trying to delete everything, except for the description text in line 570 of this index file. I want it to be variable so that I can use this script to extract the same "bullet-list drawer" description from another index file.
What I tried to use is 
`sed 's/.*overview-content\(.*div>\).*$//p'` to get a rough portion of the part I want. 
Later then I would've tried to clean it up. I am still a bit confused by the sed command ^^ 
Thank you all in advance!

https://pastebin.com/xuibF4d8

Comment: You need an HTML parser to parse HTML. Regexes cannot parse HTML.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming the input file is called *index.html*, and the desired line
   is three lines after the target string, (as it is in the cited
   pastebin data file), this should work:

   ```
   sed -n '/overview-content/{n;n;n;p;q}' index.html
   ```
2. A more flexible method, (which doesn't require the output to be three lines after), would be to scan for the first `<p>` after the target string using `grep`:

   ```
   grep -A 300 'overview-content' index.html | 
   grep -m 1 '<p>'
   ```